# Variable R returning as string in if loop?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to select all data from a column inside of a csv file for tesla shares, and find the lowest low to date. everything works, however the variable r (which is a variable that stores the data from one row and the 4th column) is not working inside the if loop that would check if it was the lowest value from the column. The error I get is that I cannot use the `<` symbol between a string and an integer, but when hovering over r it says its an integer

Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
#stock = pd.read_csv('TSLA.csv')
stock = open("TSLA.csv", 'r')#reads csv
low = 9999999999999

r = 0
dateStock = []
openStock = []
highStock = []
lowStock = []
closeStock = []
adjStock = []
volStock = []

csvreader = csv.reader(stock)
next(csvreader)

for line in stock: #looks at all the lines in the data set "stock"
    date, w, e, r, t, y, u = line.split(",")  #finds columns and assigns them to a variable
    lowStock.append(r)
    for i in range(0, len(lowStock)): #read below
        lowStock[i] = float(lowStock[i]) #converts the array from string values to int values
    if r < low:
        low = r

print(low)
```

Comment: `r` is an integer when you initialize it, but `line.split()` returns strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `r` is a string and `low` is an integer.

```
r = int(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the variable r to a float, with `r = float(r)`

Also, I would suggest unindenting the second `for` loop.

```
for line in stock: 
    date, w, e, r, t, y, u = line.split(",")
    lowStock.append(r)

for element in lowStock:
    element = float(element)
    if element < low:
        low = element

print(low)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, having a third for loop to turn r into an integer worked.